# How do I Round UP to a whole integer postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding

I have values like 10.43 and when I use the round function it puts it at 10. I want it to round up to 11 actually. Is there a way to do this?

my Code for example, I am counting number of students and dividing it by a paramer.

```
 round((cast(COUNT(Distinct s.studentnr) as numeric)/cast(:Param as numeric)),2)

-- :Param is a user input e.g. 21 or 15
```

So at the end if what I want is 52/21 = 3 (not 2)

Or will I be needing to use a case statement for this situation?

Comment: Hint:  `ceiling()`.

Comment: Ceiling, or else add 1 to the number before rounding

Comment: You want the `ceiling()` function. It does exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `ceil` function

```
 --Returns 3
 select ceil( 52.00/21)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/20356

Comment: doesn't work for me.  If I run `select ceil (61/60)` I get 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @Jacob both 60 and 61 are `int`. You divide them, you get 1 (try `select 61/60`). Then `ceil(1)` becomes 1 which makes sense. Try `select ceil (61/60::float)` and it becomes 2.